# Swift Code to Send Message Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am just learning to code and I am trying to create a simple code to send a message on IOS. I have made sure to import the MessageUI framework. When I run it on my simulator, it fails and shows THREAD 1 : SIGNAL SIGABRT. I apologize profusely if it's just a small mistake, as I often do such errors and don't wish to waste anyone's time. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI


class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
 @IBAction func SendSMS(sender: AnyObject) {
    let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    messageVC.recipients = ["5146276051"]
    messageVC.body = messageLabel.text
    messageVC.messageComposeDelegate =  self
    self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {

    switch (result.rawValue) {

    case MessageComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
        print("Message was cancelled")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    case MessageComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
        print("Message has failed")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    case MessageComposeResultSent.rawValue:
        print("Message was sent")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    default:
        break
    }
}

}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, have you connected your `IBAction` and `IBOutlet` to your storyboard files properly. SIGNAL SIGABRT is usually comes due to reasons like this. Let me know if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try to use your code on physical device, it should work.

BTW in your code please add check whether device support sending messages:

```
        @IBAction func SendSMS(sender: AnyObject) {
            //Checking whether device support message sending
            if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() == false) { return }

            let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

            messageVC.recipients = ["5146276051"]
            messageVC.body = messageLabel.text
            messageVC.messageComposeDelegate =  self
            self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

in that way you will avoid e.g. crashes on simulator.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will make sure to have a look.